# Question about using PowerShell Select-String, exiftool(-k)

Tags: powershell, start-process, select-string

In a PowerShell script I'm trying to filter the output of the `exiftool(-k).exe` command below, using `Select-String`.

I've tried numerous permutations, but none work, and I always see the unfiltered output.  What do I need to do to filter the output of this command?

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\PowerShell\exiftool(-k).exe" -ArgumentList test.jpg |
  Select-String -pattern 'GPS' -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: You say you want to filter the output, but you never explain what you're trying to filter out.  If the command you posted isn't doing what you want, and you aren't sharing what you want in the text of the post, it is difficult for people to figure out what you want.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you share sample output of the tool? Might also be worth checking if the tool outputs to `stderr` (easy to verify with `Start-Process ... 2>$null`)

Comment: I'm trying to filter out the string 'GPS' from the output.  Here's the output of the exiftool command:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.84
File Name                       : test.jpg
Directory                       : .
White Balance                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 26 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Image Unique ID                 : C12QSJB01SB
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : West
GPS Altitude Ref                : Unknown (1.7)
GPS Time Stamp                  : 23:43:26
```

Comment: Good info, but hard to see line breaks in the comment.  Maybe you can edit your original post and add the code block there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming is inconvenient.  Rename it to exiftool.exe and run it without start-process.

```
rename-item 'exiftool(-k).exe' exiftool.exe    

C:\Users\bfbarton\PowerShell\exiftool.exe test-jpg | Select-String GPS
```

Or

```
$env:path += ';C:\Users\bfbarton\PowerShell'
exiftool test.jpg | Select-String GPS
```

The website recommends to 'rename to "exiftool.exe" for command-line use'.   https://exiftool.org .  Even in unix, it wouldn't work without escaping the parentheses.

There's also the option of using the call operator.  Using tab completion actually does this:

```
& '.\exiftool(-k).exe' test.jpg | select-string gps
```

Comment: That did nothing, i.e., no output.  That was with and without the (-k).

"C:\Users\bfbarton\PowerShell\exiftool(-k).exe" | Select-String -Pattern 'GPS'

Comment: I tried it with exiftool, exiftool(-k), exiftool(-k).exe, and tried enclosing the command in quotes, but I keep getting this error:

+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-k:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks for your help that worked!  I just removed the (-k) and renamed the executable to exiftools.exe.  Good enough!

Comment: Maybe good to know: "The ExifTool application for Windows has the ability to take command-line arguments from inside the brackets in its own name." https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=12050.msg65104#msg65104

Answer (score 1):

- **You cannot directly receive output from a [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call**<sup>[1]</sup>, so **using it in a *pipeline* is pointless**.

  - In fact, on Windows your program launched with `Start-Process` runs in a *different*, new window, which is where you saw the unfiltered output (given that no `Select-String` was applied *there*); in your *calling* window, `Start-Process` produced *no output* at all, and therefore nothing was sent to `Select-String`, and the pipeline as a whole produced no output.
- Never use `Start-Process` to *synchronously* invoke a *console application* whose output you want to *capture or redirect* - simply **call the application *directly***:

```
& "C:\PowerShell\exiftool(-k).exe" test.jpg | Select-String GPS -SimpleMatch
```

Note that `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), is needed for this invocation, because your executable path is (double-)*quoted* (of necessity here, because the file name contains `(` and `)`); `&` is only needed for executable paths that are quoted and/or contain variable references; you wouldn't need it to call `git ...`, for instance.

---

<sup>[1] While you would *see* the program's output in the caller's window if you added `-NoNewWindow -Wait` to a `Start-Process` call, you still wouldn't be able to *capture*, *pass on* or *redirect* it.</sup>