# Why I am getting no out-file or no content on the text file?

Tags: powershell

Power shell script to run a batch file:

```bsh
start-Process C:\Test.bat |
Out-File C:\test.txt
```

when I check the `text.txt` file is empty?

Comment: [Joey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580096/45375) is effective; for background information, see [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60308095/45375)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Start-Process` if all you need is to run a program in the more or less default way.

```
C:\Test.bat | Out-file C:\Test.txt
```

should work fine, although you most likely lack write privileges on `C:\` so that's perhaps not the most useful path to use.

Answer (score 0):

`Start-Process` does not redirect standard output by default. You have to tell it to do so:

```
Start-Process -FilePath .\test.bat -NoNewWindow -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput ".\test.txt"
```

Note, that this will not capture errors. If you want them too, add `-RedirectStandardError ".\test-stderr.txt"`. This must be a different file than the one that you used for `-RedirectStandardOutput`.